# How to force page not to be cached in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a page, index.php, that shows information based on a mysql db.  There are forms on it, and the action for the forms is set to a separate page called process.php.  Process.php does all the database CRUD stuff, then uses

```
header("Location: /webadmin/email/index.php");
```

to send the user back to the original page.

This seems to be working fine, except for the fact that the original index page doesn't always reflect the changes made by process.php.  I assume that the page is being cached, because if I do a refresh (Ctrl + F5), the page will show the latest data.

How can I prevent this page from being cached?  I have tried [what the PHP page for header() says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), but it doesn't seem to work.  The Cache-Control and Expires options seem to have no effect at all - the page is still being cached.

**Update**

Ok, I was partially wrong.  Apparently, the following does work in IE:

```
<?php header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

However, it is definitely NOT working in FF, which is still showing a cached version.  Any ideas on why this is, and how I can make it stop caching?

Comment: bad news: http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/JDeabill/archive/2008/07/14/303.aspx

Comment: It has apparently been fixed, but i bet there are some ff versions that have experience this behaviour

Comment: I'm using the very latest version of FF, and I still see this behavior, unless I append a bogus querystring to the end of the URL.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make **all** browsers fall in line:

```
header("Location: /webadmin/email/index.php?r=".mt_rand(0, 9999999));
```

It's not pretty, but it fits the question asked: "How to ***force***..."

Comment: This seems to work fine - any body have any ideas that would be "pretty"?

Comment: It make so many cached instances on the client browser making a headache for the guy sitting there while watching at the history. It almost works, but there are better ways to do the job. and also there is a chance that a cached instance will load randomly. It's not really a good idea to be flagged as the accepted answer

Comment: @mehrdadseyrafi - Hi. Could u share yr answer. I am looking to learn. Do consider.

Answer (score 48):

I would play safely and try to output all cache killers known to man (and browser). My list currently consists of:

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the order of precedence of these different headers?  I'm sure it varies per-browser, but would be handy to know for at least IE and FF.

Comment: kill it, burn it, hurl the ashes to the sun in a sealed capsule

Comment: I just tried all the above, but it still seems to be caching the page.

Comment: @AJ sorry I don't know the order of preference, it depends really in how closely the browser follows the standards. I do know that "pragma" is for HTTP/1.0 and "cache-control" for HTTP/1.1 (i´ll edit the answer)

Comment: Would be nice, would be fine, in a perfect world… but in reality, this just doesn't work. @DerekIllchuk's solution, instead, is ugly, but it actually manages to accomplish the goal.

Comment: This one worked for me.. I had a PHP page built into a WordPress build that was using a caching module, it stopped the module from caching my page

Comment: @croceldon I don't mean to revive a mummy here but I've learned that the "all-mighty" Apple product Safari (particularly on iPad) will cache the HTML contents regardless of the header information. I would imagine they do this for "user-experience reasons" so that a user can ALWAYS rely on the back button to at minimum see the page which they were previously viewing.

Answer (score 13):

This is the correct order to get it working on all browsers:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
?>
```

Comment: You've literally just copy and pasted the [answer from @danii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1907705/851885) and rearranged the lines?

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
```

Comment: Ok - this seems to be working in IE, but it is definitely NOT working working in FF.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Try fooling the browser with a spurious querystring:

```
header("Location: /webadmin/email/index.php?x=1");
```

Comment: Yes, this is just a trick, that sometimes can be usefull, but not in this case ;)

Comment: 'Correct' isn't always practical.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

do this and it **should** prevent caching in all browsers

tested in IE FF and chrome